# ASP.NET Core deploy web app to aws ubuntu server 18. Everything is working except no css,js,jquery or bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-ec2, directory

I have deployed my .NET Core web app to aws using ubuntu server 18. I am able to hit my dns in browser and the browser loads the html, data and code, but does not load and css files, js or any scripts I have add to `layout.cshtml`. I have tried rebuilding, changing paths and researching it. People have similar issues online, but their fixes are not related to mine.

I run

```
dotnet publish --output ".\published" --configuration release
```

Inside of this folder I have runtimes folder and wwroot. Inside wwwroot I have css folder, js folder, and lib folder with all the files in each folder that I need.

In `layout.cshtml` I have my links and script paths like this

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/published/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/published/wwwroot/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/published/wwwroot/css/linkView.css" />
</head>
<footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
    </footer>
    <script src="~/published/wwwroot/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/published/wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/published/wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="~/published/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/published/wwwroot/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

I did recently add `published/wwwroot/` to each path just trying to see if that would fix it but it did nothing.

And in the browser I get these errors:

[image]

[image]

Basically all 404 errors, it cannot find my files and I do not understand why. Anyone have this issue or see the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your paths are wrong. Please try to remove `/published/wwwroot`

E.g.: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/published/wwwroot/css/site.css" />`
should be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />`

Comment: I had what you posted first as default for paths. I switched the path just trying to see if it would work. The problem was I ftped the published folder into my ubuntu server. Instead you are supposed go into your published/build folder and ftp everything inside of it to your ubuntu server